# Unity, C#: Delay on function not working? Waitforseconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a VR app using Google Cardboard in Unity and I have succeeded in switching from VR to a normal view with this function:

```
public GameObject[] cardboardObjects;
    public GameObject[] monoObjects;
    public bool switched = false;

    // Turn on or off VR mode
    void ActivateVRMode(bool goToVR) {
        foreach (GameObject cardboardThing in cardboardObjects) {
            cardboardThing.SetActive(goToVR);
        }
        foreach (GameObject monoThing in monoObjects) {
            monoThing.SetActive(!goToVR);
        }
        Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = goToVR;

        // Tell the game over screen to redisplay itself if necessary
        //gameObject.GetComponent<GameController>().RefreshGameOver();
    }
```

I then call this function on a button to switch to mono view:

```
public void Switch() {
        ActivateVRMode(false);
        switched = true;
        Debug.Log (switched+"No VR!");
    }
```

I then want to have the mono view on a timer, as in once the user switches to non-VR mode it remains in that for only a set amount of time (3 seconds or so) before switching back to VR.

I tried to do this by flipping a boolean and using `WaitForSeconds`, however the view remains in mono view and nothing happens:

```
IEnumerator Switchback() 
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); 
            ActivateVRMode(true);
            switched = false;
            Debug.Log (switched+"VR!");
    }

    void Update () {

        if (switched == true) {
            Switchback ();
        }

        //Debug.Log ("updating");

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Dude don't forget to accept the answer below. That is the problem you are having. gjttt1 has a solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to call the `Switchback` function as a Coroutine

Instead of calling `Switchback()` you need to call `StartCoroutine(Switchback())` in your `Update()` function.